# Browse option of IIS 7.5 does nothing

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a virtual directory and inside it a simple .htm file. When I go to content view and then right click and browse actually nothing happen, nothing. It even doesn't open any browser. On the other hand, If I open the browser and type the .htm file, I can see the page.
What can I do to make browse working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem occured because of the settings that can be accidently changed. So I tried to unistall and reinstall to turn back defaults.

I first unistalled both IIS (Internet Information Services) and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) because we are trying to remove "ApplicationHost.config". After unistallaing them I reinstalled and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 6):

This issue typically occurs when the topmost binding in Site Bindings points to something not browsable.

In my case I had net.msmq binding that prevented the services from browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue today , IISReset and machine restart corrected the issue for me.